# Проблема при сравнении возврата от функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#AOptions").change(function() {
      var readySet = makeSetOfAttrValues($("#ATemplate > form"));
      switch ($("#AOptions option:selected").val()) {
        case "1":
          var formAttr = $("#CreateCompanyHandler").attr("id");
          if (equals(readySet, formAttr) === true) {
            createCompany(); // Не вызывается данный метод! В чём может быть проблема ?
          }
          break;

          function equals(setOfAttr, formAttr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < setOfAttr.length; i++) {
              if (setOfAttr[i] === formAttr) {
                return true;
              }
            }
          }

          function makeSetOfAttrValues(value) {
            var attrValues = [];
            value.map(function() {
              attrValues.push($(this).attr("id"));
            });
            return attrValues;
          }
```

Comment: Например, в несоответствии типов. Попробуйте заменить все `===` на `==`. Или в массиве правда нет такого id

Comment: Не помогает. Происходят сравнения до момента вызова вункции createCompany(). После этого программа останавливается. На протяжении всего алгоритма нет никаких ошибок, при debugging программа идёт хорошо до этого момента.

Comment: Что возвращает функция `equals`? Что значит "программа останавливается"?

Comment: equals возврашает true, там равзе не видно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше воспользоваться методом [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (readySet.indexOf(formAttr) > -1) {
    createCompany();
}
```

Comment: Не пойму как она возврашает несколько ответов ? Если при выводе на консоль для проверки она возврашает один ответ.